# Still able to select disabled checkbox in Mat table

Tags: angular, checkbox, mat-table

I have Mat table with a checkbox column. I am setting certain checkboxes to disabled based on certain conditions. However the user is still able to select the checkbox if the click on the row. How do I prevent the checkbox from being selected when disabled: Here is a stackblitz example I forked from the material design site: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-erpaus?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.html. you can't click the check box but if you click outside of it the checkbox gets selected: [image]

```
<mat-checkbox (click)=      "$event.stopPropagation()"
                              (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) :null"
                              [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)" 
                              [disabled]="myCondition"
                               color="primary">
                </mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: remove  `(click)="selection.toggle(row)"` from tr-mat-row

Comment: @AmitBaranes or use a condition that is similar to the disabled condition on it too

Comment: Thanks That worked. But why does `selection.toggle(row)` allow that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AmitBaranes says remove `(click)="selection.toggle(row)"` should work, but you will not be able to select a row if the condition is `true`.
If you want to disable certain rows and enable others you could implement the condition like this `(click)="!row.excluded && selection.toggle(row)"`.
See the full example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-disable-row).

Answer (score 1):

I think, when you click on row, the row is select. In your code: `[checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"` checks if row is selected and when this expression return true, checkbox will select so you must turn off selecting row after click.